# Dynamically display total length of polyline feature class in miles using Arcade expression?

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcade

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.0. I would like to use Insert Table Attribute on a layout to display the total length (in miles) of a polyline feature class. I want this to be dynamic -- not a field calculate or a statistic. I can display all of the line lengths by just using an Arcade expression - `$feature.Shape__Length`. How can I return just the total length?

Comment: Lengths are only stored in feet, and we don’t have a field to store miles. It seems that this would be the only way, but so redundant. If only I could pass the Sum as a number and the divide by 5280.

Comment: OK, that does make it a little more tricky.  Could you please edit your original question post to include this information?

Comment: I've updated my answer to cater for non-miles length attribute (although I've not tried that dynamic text conversion technique myself, others there seem to confirm that it works).

Answer (score 1):

Use the 'Sum' option in the 'Table Statistics' section of the 'Dynamic Text' feature, instead.  Ie...

Insert -> Dynamic Text -> Table Statistics -> Sum

Then configure the dialogue options as desired (layer/table, field, statistic (sum), etc).

If your length attribute is in some unit other than miles, then you can use the dynamic text conversion technique described in BrettGovernanti1's answer at:  https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/calculate-values-using-dynamic-text/td-p/213567